# XNA foreach statement error

Tags: foreach, xna

I keep getting this error in the code below. can somebody tell me what I did Wrong.
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'method group' because 'method group' does not contain a public definition for

```
 private void updateVelocity(KeyboardState keyboardState)
        {
    var keysdictionay = new Dictionary<Keys, Vector2>
    {
    {Keys.Left, new Vector2(-1, 0)},
    {Keys.Right, new Vector2(1, 0)},

    {Keys.Up, new Vector2(0, -1)},
    {Keys.Down, new Vector2(0, 1)}
     };

    var velocity = Vector2.Zero;
    foreach (var keypress in keyboardState.GetPressedKeys)
    {

    velocity += keysdictionay[keypress];

    }

    Velocity = velocity * shipspeed;
    }

    public Vector2 Velocity { get; set; }

    float shipspeed = 300.0f;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`GetPressedKeys is a method.`  use `()` on it

```
foreach (var keypress in keyboardState.GetPressedKeys())
```